# Function for finding an empty space in an area, how to return an error if none is found?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

The function, FindEmptySpace() below finds a random empty space in an area. It does this by picking random coordinates within the area, checks if anything already exists there, and then loops this process until it successfully finds a location with nothing there and then returns it.

It works great but I just realized this could end up in a never-ending loop if there's no free space available. But how can the function know when there's no empty space available and return an error?

```
static function FindEmptySpace ()
{
    var sphereRadius = 2.0;
    while ( true )
    {
        var spawnPos = RandomPoint();   // Get random position within level bounds

        if ( !Physics.CheckSphere( spawnPos, sphereRadius ) )   // Check if area is empty
        break;  
    }
    return spawnPos;    // Return empty location
}
```

Comment: Why not enumerate all possible spawn locations ahead of time and just track when one is used?  Would also save on recalculating a free space.  Or subtract the volume of each smaller sphere from the larger sphere until ~75% of the larger sphere's volume is taken up by small spheres, at which point it's ~full(this accounts for 'airgap')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rewrote it to Renan's suggestion and now loop to the edges of the boundary, and if we reach the starting point again, we have not found anything and return null.

Untested but I assume this is a good solution.

```
static function CheckForEmptySpace ()
{
    var bounds = GameController.levelAttributes.bounds;
    var sphereRadius = 2.0;
    var startingPos = Vector3( Random.Range(bounds.xMin, bounds.xMax), 0, Random.Range(bounds.yMin, bounds.yMax) );
    // Loop, until empty adjacent space is found
    var spawnPos = startingPos; 
    while ( true )
    {
        if ( !Physics.CheckSphere( spawnPos, sphereRadius ) )   // Check if area is empty
            return spawnPos;    // Return location
        else
        {
            // Not empty, so gradually move position down. If we hit the boundary edge, move and start again from the opposite edge.
            var shiftAmount = 2;
            spawnPos.z -= shiftAmount;
            if ( spawnPos.z < bounds.yMin )
            {
                spawnPos.z = bounds.yMax;
                spawnPos.x += shiftAmount;
                if ( spawnPos.x > bounds.xMax )
                    spawnPos.x = bounds.xMin;
            }
            // If we reach back to a close radius of the starting point, then we didn't find any empty spots
            var proximity = (spawnPos - startingPos).sqrMagnitude;
            var range = shiftAmount-0.1;    // Slight 0.1 buffer so it ignores our initial proximity to the start point
            if ( proximity < range*range )  // Square the range
            {
                Debug.Log( "An empty location could not be found" );
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because even if it is not 100% correct (I can't tell without testing, but I think it is correct), this is a good reference on how to do it for someone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't keep looking for random points - there is no guarantee that it will ever stop. Even though it's quite improbable, it is possible for example for the alghoritm to keep checking the exact same point for days before switching to some other.

Instead, pick one point (which may be random), check if it's empty or not... And then check the next adjacent one. Do this until you've checked them all. You need a way to avoid checking the same point twice. Seeing each and every point as a node in a graph will allow you to search for empty ones efficiently. Then, when the function is done, you can be 100% sure whether there is an empty space or not, and raise an error accordingly.

Comment: That's why OP asked this question: How to go about this as efficiently as possible, avoiding dead-locks